# PHP protected function call in child class

Tags: php, class, oop, protected

I know how to call a protected function in a child class. Are there any other methods to call a protected function in a child class besides demonstrated below?

```
My Parent Calss {

    class myadmin {

        function __construct() {
        }

        protected function _layouts(){
            return "Hello world";                
        }

}
```

**Child Class**

```
class adminpanel extend myadmin {

    public function index() {
        $this->_layouts();
        // or 
        parent::_layouts();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you need to know multiple methods? Just use `$this->_layouts()`

Comment: You're just being confuse as to which to use. `parent` or `$this`, Both would do,

Comment: Sidenote: Using an underscore to indicate that a method is private/protected is against the PSR coding standards and honestly, looks ugly.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763999/access-protected-method-from-child-class-in-php?rq=1

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237511/multiple-ways-of-calling-parent-method-in-php

Comment: this is secure to pass the protected function to child class..?

Comment: @john , access modifiers is not about security, what are trying to implement?